# CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO curInfo : what's the meaning of this function

Tags: c++

This is the part of TETRISS sorce code. I don't know the meaning of  `CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO curInfo` in the bottom of that function. Why this have
to be used? please answer....

```
void removeCursor(void) 
{ 
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO curInfo; 
    GetConsoleCursorInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &curInfo); 
    curInfo.bVisible=0; 
    SetConsoleCursorInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &curInfo); 
}
```

Comment: Need more context here to know why those functions are used. As for those functions, you can find what they do just by googling them. Here is one of them on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686019%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that struct holds info about the cursor, like blink rate or position. In this case, it is disabling the blinking you get from a console cursor.